# Have a feed for Hot Network Questions in Chat or Seperate Room

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Can we have a feed in chat for Hot Network Questions?

This could help us:

- See what questions are hot just out of interest
- Pay special attention to edging them

An example of what this could look like is [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92126/hotness) on Ask Different or we could have it in the main room.

What does everyone think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feed is posted [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98630/hot-network-questions-feed), with a link to the actual feed [here](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/travel.stackexchange.com).

This was adapted from the [Ask Different](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/apple.stackexchange.com) feed for our site.